# Observable<string> updated events?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, system.reactive

I'm just trying to do a simple event handler on a string variable, so that if the string changes, it will do a Console.WriteLine (using the new Reactive library from MS (Rx))

The issue that I have is that it will display the first bit when I instantiate the class ("RandomGuid : Mine?"), but after that, none of the stuff I change afterwards spits anything out to the console.

I went through the HOL from the MS website, but it goes straight from defining the Observable into reading values from a textbox, when all I want to do is watch whether a string was changed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MynahBirds
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Minah> minahs = new List<Minah>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                minahs.Add(new Minah());
            }

            foreach (var item in minahs) {
                item.peers = minahs;
            }

            minahs.ForEach(m => m.s = Observable.Return<string>("Mine"));
            minahs.ForEach(m => m.s = Observable.Return<string>("Whee"));
            minahs.ForEach(m => m.s = Observable.Return<string>("Argh"));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class Minah
    {
        Guid Id;
        public List<Minah> peers;
        IDisposable subscription;

        public IObservable<string> s = Observable.Return<string>("Mine?");

        public Minah()
        {
            try {
                this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

                subscription = s.Subscribe((string a) => {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", this.Id, a);
                },
                (Exception ex) => {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error {0} hit", ex.ToString());
                },
                () => { });

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if it's logical to observe a string. strings are immutable, so they never change.

Comment: Are you sure there is no dysfunctionality caused by differences between "Mine" and "Mine?"

Comment: It was just a toy app for me to get the concept down.  My goal is to actually pass doubles and neurons to acknowledge signals + linking axons to dendrites -- but I figured it would be better to use strings to see a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you assign to `m.s` in the `ForEach` you are not updating the existing observable (which you have subscribed to) with a new value, instead you are creating new observables, which is what `Observable.Return` does. The code below does what I think you expect:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MynahBirds
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Minah> minahs = new List<Minah>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                minahs.Add(new Minah());
            }

            foreach (var item in minahs)
            {
                item.peers = minahs;
            }

            minahs.ForEach(m => m.s.OnNext("Mine"));
            minahs.ForEach(m => m.s.OnNext("Whee"));
            minahs.ForEach(m => m.s.OnNext("Argh"));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class Minah
    {
        Guid Id;
        public List<Minah> peers;
        IDisposable subscription;

        public ISubject<string> s = new Subject<string>();

        public Minah()
        {
            try
            {
                this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

                subscription = s.Subscribe((string a) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", this.Id, a);
                },
                (Exception ex) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error {0} hit", ex.ToString());
                },
                () => { });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of using `Observable.Return<T>()`, here I use a `Subject`, which is both an observer and an observable sequence. It updates all its subscriptions with each value it observes. So when `OnNext` is called on the subject, it is forwarded to all subscriptions.

If you need the initial value (`Mine?`) you can add `s.OnNext("Mine?");` at the end of the `Minah` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

namespace MynahBirds
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(100, 100);

            ConcurrentBag<Minah> minahs = new ConcurrentBag<Minah>();
            Stopwatch ti = new Stopwatch();

            ti.Start();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                for (int i = 1; i < 2501; i++) {
                    minahs.Add(new Minah(i));
                };
            });

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                for (int i = 1; i < 2501; i++) {
                    minahs.Add(new Minah(i));
                };
            });

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                for (int i = 1; i < 2501; i++) {
                    minahs.Add(new Minah(i));
                };
            });

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                for (int i = 1; i < 2501; i++) {
                    minahs.Add(new Minah(i));
                };
            });

            Task.WaitAll();

            string[] alpha = { "Alpha", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Eagle", "Foxtrot", "Gulf", "Hotel" };

            foreach (string s in alpha) {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => minahs.AsParallel().ForAll(m => m.RepeatWord = s)).Wait();
            }

            minahs.AsParallel().ForAll(m => m.s.OnCompleted());

            ti.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine("{1} birds : {0} seconds", ti.Elapsed.TotalSeconds, minahs.Count);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class Minah
    {
        Guid Id;
        IDisposable subscription;

        public ISubject<string> s = new Subject<string>();

        private string _RepeatWord;
        public string RepeatWord
        {
            get
            {
                return _RepeatWord;
            }
            set
            {
                this.s.OnNext(value);
                _RepeatWord = value;
            }
        }

        public Minah(int i)
        {
            try {
                this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

                subscription = s.Subscribe((string a) => {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", i, a);
                },
                (Exception ex) => {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error {0} hit", ex.ToString());
                },
                () => { /* Console.WriteLine("{0} : Completed", this.Id); */ });

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I ended up doing with help from Markus.  More playing around with parallelism.  Interestingly, if I remove the .Wait() from the end of the .ForAll(... RepeatWord = s), it will only do the last word in the sequence. I'm guessing that is a closure thing, but I'm not overly concerned about it.